# Problems accessing datasource in Karaf 4 from Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I've created a datasource in Karaf 4 (ServiceMix 7) that works from the karaf console - I can list tables, execute queries and so on.
My issue is when I try to use it from my Camel route.

Excerpt from my blueprint:

```
...
<reference filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/erp)" id="erpDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
...
<to id="erpSelectQuery" uri="jdbc:erpDataSource"/>
...
```

It finds my dataSource but the blueprint can't start due to:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified"
```

My datasource was created using:

```
jdbc:ds-create -dbName erp -dt DataSource -dn mysql -u erp -dc com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -p pre jdbc/erp
```

I'm at loss here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done it via the jdbc command syntax I followed the guides from the [Ops4J Wiki On Datasource creation](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config) which I like for one reason alone, this method creates a simple text file that can be administered by not just a Java developer, i.e. it is easier to modify and troubleshoot.

For the sake of not subjecting my answer to link rot I will just outline the procedure here.

Create a datasource configuration file(simple text file) in /servicemixhome/etc with the following naming convention `org.ops4j.datasource-give_your_datasource_a_name.cfg` .

In the config file configure the appropriate settings an example of mine looks like this:

```
    osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    databaseName=dhData
    user=foo
    url=jdbc:mysql://192.199.199.199:3306/dhData
    password=somepassword
    dataSourceName=myDSName
```

Make sure you installed the ops4j required features:

```
feature:install pax-jdbc-mysql pax-jdbc-config
```

Now list the datasources using the following syntax:

```
karaf@root()> service:list javax.sql.DataSource
```

This will echo something like the list below back.

```
[javax.sql.DataSource]
----------------------

    osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    databaseName=dhData
    user=foo
    url=jdbc:mysql://192.199.199.199:3306/dhData
    password=somepassword
    dataSourceName=myDSName 
Provided by : 
    OPS4J Pax JDBC Config (216)
```

At this point you can reference the datasource usign an osgi filter in the blueprint.xml with the following syntax:

```
<reference filter="(&amp;(objectClass=javax.sql.DataSource)(dataSourceName=myDSName ))" id="myData" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Then to reference this as property of a bean for example you could do the following:

```
    <bean class="foo.bar" id="ImsCbrEventsBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myData"/>
    </bean>
```

Keep in mind this creates a singular connection to a database and you should really create a connection pool.

This can be done by installing the pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2 feature or any of the other connection pools but use only one at a time, then modifying the datasource config file to carry appropriate information like the example below:

```
    osgi.jdbc.driver.name = mysql
    databaseName=dhData
    user=foo
    url=jdbc:mysql://192.199.199.199:3306/dhData
    password=somepassword
    dataSourceName=myDSName 
    jdbc.pool.maxTotal=32
    jdbc.pool.blockWhenExhausted=true
    jdbc.pool.lifo=false
    jdbc.pool.maxIdle=24
    jdbc.pool.maxWaitMillis=5000
    jdbc.pool.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
    jdbc.pool.minIdle=16
    jdbc.pool.numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
    jdbc.pool.softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis=-1
    jdbc.pool.testOnBorrow=true
    jdbc.pool.testOnCreate=true
    jdbc.pool.testOnReturn=true
    jdbc.pool.testWhileIdle=true
    jdbc.pool.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=3600000
```

Comment: You should never use  osgi.jdbc.driver.name  and osgi.jdbc.driver.class. Use only one of these.

Comment: Thanks,
I actually did it the same way using a config file. I can list the service ok and camel finds the datasource since I'm getting another message if I enter an invalid JNDI name. Your filter looks slightly different than mine but when trying that syntax I'm getting the same error.

I'm assuming that it'd work if I passed the datasource to a bean but I'd like to use the JDBC component for this case.  
I've successfully used the camel components while defining the datasource directly in the blueprint but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider agreed. Copying and pasting with conjunctivitis is also not recommended.

Comment: @user5188655 could you maybe share how you are defining the JDBC component?

Comment: @user5188655 see this link  https://beroslingblade.wordpress.com/2016/03/28/osgi-registry-datasourcefactory-mybatis/

Comment: If defining the DataSource in blueprint worked then using a <reference> with the same id should also work.

Comment: That was my expectation/understanding @ChristianSchneider but alas, I'm getting this connectionFactory error.

Comment: @Namphibian how we can get datasource from registry in Camel JavaDSL 
select * from table where id=# order by name?dataSource=myDS